# Is it possible to add a intermediate filter layer in apache?

Tags: apache

We know the model: `Browser --- Apache --- WebApplication`.

In my Browser, I access the web by `example.com/admin`, then it through the Apache to WebApplication.

I have a request, wether can we make a intermediate filter layer in Apache,

when I in browser access by `example.com/admin?id=1&key=aaa`, in the Apache intermediate filter layer it check the id and key, then get rid of the `?id=1&key=aaa` and send `example.com/admin` to WebApplication, then send back.

Comment: what would be the purpose? Render your webapplication unusable? The knowledge about `id` and other parameters is fully your webapplication's knowledge and I can't imagine making their valid content known to Apache would add any additional security over sensible parameter value checking in the webapplication. It'll need to handle bogus data anyway, and the right place to detect it is where you know what that data means - in your webapp

Comment: I want to add the `id` and `key` in the end of URL, so not everyone can access the `/admin` directly.